# Facebook login missing from mobile

Tags: bug, android-app, login

When I first signed up, I used the Facebook login option. However, Facebook login is missing from the mobile app - only Google, SE and OpenID are available. I then tried Google, but I got the error shown in the screenshot below:

> [image: login screen with error].

How can I login with the app?

Comment: Presumably this is for Android. Do you have a Facebook account on your device under `Settings > Accounts`?

Comment: Hrm, no. I use Facebook on Chrome because it is too heavy for my phone.

Comment: Surprisingly, Facebook login is now an option now that I installed it, however I get the same error when trying to login with.